# Recommended way to store data securely using Cordova?

Tags: cordova

What is the recommended way to securely store data locally using Cordova?  I don't really want to save it in LocalStorage since the data is in SQLite db and is easily viewed on a rooted device.

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_security_index.md.html
Says not to cache any sensitive data but I was wondering if there are any 3rd party alternatives you are using.

Comment: on iOS there is a plugin for storing on the keychain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WebSql : http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase

or Cordova SQLite Plugin : https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage